# Google map API Sharing data between sibling components using service Angular2

Tags: google-maps, angular, typescript, angular2-services, angular-services

I want to pass data from one component to another when the user clicks on the map marker.
I have two components-right(displays map) and left(displays the title of clicked marker).
I am using service for this purpose.

right component.ts

```
google.maps.event.addListener(markerarray[i], 'click', ( (marker, i)=> {
   return function () {
       Content = "Name :" + locations[i][0] + '<br> Latitude:' + locations[i][1] + '<br> Longitude:' + locations[i][2];
       infowindow.setContent(Content);
       infowindow.open(map, this);
       this.dataservice.pushData(markerarray[i].title); //This is not working for me
   }      
})(marker, i));
```

data.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  constructor() { }

  pushdeata=new EventEmitter<string>();
  pushData(value:string) {
    this.pushedata.emit(value);
  }
```

left.component.ts

```
declare var google: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-left',
  templateUrl: './left.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./left.component.css']
})
export class LeftComponent implements OnInit {
  value='';

  constructor(private dataservice: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
     this.dataservice.pushdata.subscribe(
        data => this.value = data
     );
  }}
```

left.component.html

```
<div>{{value}}<div>
```

Comment: Is the right and left component in a parent component? Then you can use the parent component for notifying the left that a marker has been clicked.

Comment: what do you mean by this is not working for me? Are you not getting instance of dataservice or you are not able to call function?

Comment: You may have misspelled `pushdeata`